# Make the site use up only the height of the browser window

Tags: html, css

I have a really stupid problem, my site should only take the height of the browser window, it should never be bigger. That's because I basically have two div's pn there and inside of the divs the content shall get a scrollbar, but never the overall page. The first div does not have a fixed width, but the second does.

Code:

```
<div class="overall"> <!-- the overall site should always have the height of the 
browser window, it shall never be bigger and never have a scrollbar, only the areas part and the log part should each have a scrollbar -->
<div class="areas"> <!-- the div without fixed height -->
    <div class="area">
    </div>
    <div class="area">
    </div>
    <div class="area">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="log"> <!-- the div with a fixed height -->
</div>
```

```
.area {
    height: 72px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.areas {
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.log {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

Here's my fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lunaetic/p9uzzmfc/3/)

It just doesn't work that my site only takes the height of the browser window.

Comment: use `html,body{max-height:100vh}`

Comment: Doesn't this quality as an answer?

Comment: yeah, weird that - clearly shows there's an answer on question list page

Comment: Thank you @Professor.CSS, it works (: If you'd put this down as an answer I'd accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in using `vh` (view port height) units.

These are relevant to the physical size of the screen.

for example, if I set a div to be `50vh`, it will be 50% height of whatever the user's screen.

In your case, setting 100vh as a max-height on your html and body would mean the user cannot make the height or body over whatever the can see (if that makes sense).

Demo:

```css
html{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  max-height:100vh;
  }
body{
  margin:0;padding:0;
  height:50vh; /*need this since I've no content on my page to begin with!*/
  max-height:50vh;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
```

---

This can obviously be reduced using the `,` seperator into:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;padding:0;
  height:100vh; /*ensures full screen even if content is shorter*/
  max-height:50vh;
  }
```

With this in place, the user will not be able to extend the content.

---

Need to

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
.area {
  height: 72px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.areas {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.log {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) { 
  /*anything placed here will come into play when the height of view is 500px or less. here I have decided to hide the areas divs so that the .log can be seen in full*/
  .areas {
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overall">
  <!-- the overall site should always have the height of the 
browser window, it shall never be bigger and never have a scrollbar, only the areas part and the log part should each have a scrollbar -->
  <div class="areas">
    <!-- the div without fixed height -->
    <div class="area">
    </div>
    <div class="area">
    </div>
    <div class="area">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="log">
    <!-- the div with a fixed height -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much (: another small question: Do you know how I can make the upper div shrink and get a scrollbar once the window height gets smaller? So that the log part keeps his size, but the areas div shrinks and gets a scrollbar (which is why the areas div does not have a fixed height).

Comment: use something like a media query for that. see my edit.

Comment: But the div should not disappear, it should just become smaller with a scrollbar